# Exist vs exists in mathematics

Tags: word-usage, singular-vs-plural, ellipsis, mathematics

Are there any rules about when to say **exist** and when to say **exists** in mathematics? For example, both these sentences appear in a book of mine:

> There exist *α<sub>i</sub>* in *I* such that *x<sub>n</sub>* = Σ *α<sub>i</sub> x<sub>i</sub>*.
>
> There exists *s''* in *S* such that *s''*(*s'm* – *sm'*) = 0.

I'm a bit confused about when to use **exist** and when **exists**.

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/46831/be-used-vs-to-be-used-to

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Exists** and **exist** follow the ordinary convention for verbs: one is singular and the other is plural. Where mathematical usage differs from ordinary usage is in the way singular and plural are indicated in the *subject* that follows, and an implied “for all” later if the subject is plural.

**Exists** is singular:

> There exists *s''* in *S* such that *s''*(*s'm* – *sm'*) = 0.

Or, spelled out more explicitly:

> There exists a number *s''* in the set *S*, such that *s''*(*s'm* – *sm'*) = 0.

**Exist** is plural:

> There exist *α<sub>i</sub>* in *I* such that *x<sub>n</sub>* = Σ *α<sub>i</sub> x<sub>i</sub>*.

This is where the mathematical usage differs from ordinary usage. Spelled out explicitly, this would be:

> There exist numbers *α<sub>1</sub>*, *α<sub>2</sub>*, *α<sub>3</sub>*, etc., which are elements of the set *I*, such that **for each** subscript, if we refer to the subscript as *i*, then *x<sub>n</sub>* = Σ *α<sub>i</sub> x<sub>i</sub>*.

The convention is tricky for a beginner to understand because it depends on your knowing that *i* is commonly used as a variable that will stand for multiple subscripts. The plural form of “exist” is actually a helpful clue. However, you must understand the implied “for each” later in the sentence. It’s implied by the fact that the sentence uses *i* to stand for multiple values.

Answer (score 2):

I would say some author would like to use "there exist" as a direct translation of the existential quantifier. In this case, like in your case, the author does not bother to fit his writing in a plain English context. Note that if your readers are all mathematicians or people with pure mathematics background, then you need not worry about such a usage would confuse your reader.

Nevertheless, I prefer to write, for example: *"For every real number ϵ there is a real number δ such that ..."* or *"There are integers x, y, z such that x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup> = z<sup>2</sup> "* or *"There is a triple of integers $x, y, z$ such that x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup> = z<sup>2</sup>.*

The case that interests you is not the only case. For instance, we can easily find that some author would write *"Given ϵ > 0, ..."* instead of *"Given an ϵ > 0".*

A beautiful mathematical writing should be like the author is talking and walking with the reader.

If you are interested, please be referred to [How to write mathematics](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Eazoff/courses/halmos.pdf)