# "exist" vs. "there are"

Tags: word-usage, difference

Which of the following sentences is more natural or normal, is there any difference?

> - Currently, **there are** powerful query languages for XML.
> - Currently, powerful query languages **exist** for XML.

What are the other alternatives?

Comment: The "there are" form is considered less formal. Not "informal" exactly, but less elaborate.

Comment: **Currently** is unnecessary. "At this time" is implied in the present tense verb.

Comment: @TRomano, Isn't that true of practically all sentences with "currently"?

Comment: There are times when "currently" fits and times when it doesn't. There are currently five people ahead of you in the queue.  Yes.  There is currently no cure for Alzheimers.  Yes.  There is currently a polio vaccine. Otiose, and not quite what *currently* means.  Things that exist currently or don't exist currently are subject to change. But once something exists and will continue to exist, we don't say "currently".  There are currently 50 states. With Puerto Rico, it could be 51.  Yes. The United States is currently between Canada and Mexico.  No.

Comment: @TRomano thank you for the point! it seems I should say it as "there are powerful query languages for XML " or use "*Today" and say "Today, three are powerful query languages for XML*", maybe to emphasize that they were not before but they are in access at the present time. Anyway, I think I need to refer to the present time. However, as I searched other articles they most use "currently" rather than "today".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both seem natural to me. I'd use both without hesitating.

> What are the other alternatives?

I actually can't think of any without making the sentence *clumsy*

It's possible to say:

> Currently, there exist some powerful query languages for XML

but this sounds *mathematical*, sounding similar to "For every x, there exists a y such that..." so I wouldn't use it.

Comment: I'd say the alternative you give works, but should be "there exist" as "languages" is the subject (cf. http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/46968/25308)

Comment: What about this alternative *Currently, powerful query languages **are available** for XML.*

Comment: Yeah Ahmad, that's fine. There certainly are other ways to say what you want, but I couldn't think of any quickly.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I don't think there's a clear answer. Both sentences convey the information without coming off as pompous. I agree with the other answerers to drop "Currently".