# Explanation of "does there exist"?

Tags: word-usage, idioms, expressions

I wrote in a forum:

> Does **exists** any other approaches?

Someone suggests me to write:

> Does **there exist** any other approaches?

I made some researches on the web and I found that the latter expression is the common, and maybe right, form.

I'm looking for a deep understanding of such expression.

Comment: I am a native English speaker, and I must confess, I don't know the grammatical reason _why_ **there** is required. I just know it "sounds wrong" without it.

Comment: Using the singular "does" with the plural "approaches" still sounds wrong; I think it should be "Do there exist any other approaches?".

Comment: But to do a more aggressive copy-edit, something like "What other options are there?" is more idiomatic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Do/does

A verb takes its infinitive form when combined with auxiliary **do**:

> **Do** ghosts **exist**?
>
> **Does** God **exist**?

Notice that **exist** does not agree with the subject. The choice of **do** or **does** agrees with the subject. **Do** and **ghosts** are both plural; **does** and **God** are both singular.

Since this is a question, you need the inverted form, where auxiliary **do** precedes the subject and the main verb follows the subject:

> **Do** any other approaches **exist**?

### There are/exist

In English, we [don't usually use](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is%2Cexists%2Care%2Cexist&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cexists%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Care%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cexist%3B%2Cc0) the verb **exist**. Usually we use the dummy subject **there** with **be**, like this:

> **Are there** any other approaches?
>
> Yes, **there are** other approaches.

That's probably how you should say it. Usually we say **exist** to talk about whether something is real or a superstition, for emphasis, or to speak precisely and technically, as in [mathematics](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/46960/6700). By using **exist** when searching for a possible method ("approach") for doing something, you make the listener wonder if you mean something like what people ordinarily use **exist** to mean.

However, for that reason, saying **exist** where **be** is customary makes your point more forcefully. In an appropriate context, if you say "Do any other approaches **exist**?", people will understand this as a rhetorical question: that is, you mean "Stop searching for something that might not even exist! Let's choose the approach that we already know."

### Do there exist

It is within the limits of grammaticality to combine dummy **there** with **exist**, but it sounds awkward:

> **Do there exist** any other approaches?

Most people perceive this as clumsy English. Often in English, we do get clarity by combining multiple ways of suggesting the same thing, but combining dummy **there** with **exist** sounds overly wordy. I don't know if there is a principled explanation for why. English works more by customary phrases than by rules, so there might not be a rule here. In mathematics, **does there exist** does not sound as clumsy, because **there exists** is a very common phrase in mathematics.

> **Does there exist** a greatest prime number? *[Ordinary and clear in mathematics.]*
>
> **Does** a greatest prime number **exist**? *[A little strange-sounding in mathematics.]*
>
> **Does there exist** a credible presidential candidate? *[A little strange-sounding in everyday English.]*
>
> **Does** a credible presidential candidate **exist**? *[Emphatic everyday English, suggesting doubt about something ordinarily taken for granted.]*

Comment: I think a lot has to do with whether the reader should use the description to try to identify a known object to which the rest of the sentence will be applied, or should focus upon the description *itself* as a means of synthesizing objects.  The construct "does there exist an X such that..." prepares the listener to try to synthesize objects meeting the following description.  By contrast, "Does an X such that ... exist"? makes the reader parse the whole description before knowing what to do with it.

Comment: I appreciated the contextualization a lot, specially the difference between "exist" and "there be".

Also the "ngram" reference was a good point.

Answer (score 10):

It's not really too complicated.  Firstly, think of the *statement* you're asking about:

> There exist other approaches.

*There* in this case is a [dummy subject](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/dummy-subjects); in English, you can't just have a verb with no subject, and we usually use *it* or *there*.  For example, you have to say

> There are six possibilities.

and not

> Are six possibilities.

When you make a statement about a verb into a question in English, you use *do* and change the word order.  For example.

> *He eats fish.* / **Does he eat fish?**
>   *They live in Hoboken*. / **Do they live in Hoboken?**

You're asking a question about the statement "There exist other approaches", so it follows the exact same pattern:

> *There exist other approaches.*  / **Do there exist (any) other approaches?**

We have to have *there* in the sentence because it's still the dummy subject, which we need; you can't say "Does exist X?" or "Do exist X?" because there's no subject in it.  It should also be *Do* if you're talking about *approaches*, because *approaches* is plural: *it does*, but *they do*.

Comment: This would be even more useful if it addressed the fact that the existential construction with *there* is only **necessary** if the underlying verb is *BE*; with *exist* it is simpler to say *Do any other approaches exist?*

Comment: @StoneyB - A good point; I thought about getting into the difference between "There exists X" and "X exists".  Maybe I should add it.

Comment: Nobody lives in Hoboken, there isn't any room.

Answer (score 3):

When the subject and the verb are reversed to make a question, in modern English it is only the auxiliary and the subject that are inverted, the main verb still follows the subject. (Perhaps that is why we use "do" to form questions, so that there is an auxiliary to be inverted).

So the question corresponding to

> Other approaches exist.

would be:

> Do other approaches exist?

and that is perfectly grammatical.

But "exist" has an alternative sentence frame with a dummy subject "there", and the logical subject in the complement position:

> There exist[s] other approaches.

and the question form of this is

> Do[es] there exist any other approaches?

In contrast,

> *Does exist any other approaches?

is not grammatical, because only the auxilliary is inverted with the subject, not the whole verb phrase (except occasionally in poetry).

(I put the endings in brackets because there is some disagreement about whether to use a singular or plural verb in this construction. The grammatical subject is "there", which is singular, and the traditional rule says that the verb should be singlar "exists" and "does"; but many people in sentences like this make the verb agree with the logical subject, and say "exist" and "do". I would say that at present, both options are grammatical).

Other verbs which can take this sentence frame include "appear", and "follow". It is something of a literary construction, and "there exists" is particularly used in academic writing.

> There appeared a small man from behind the counter.
>
> There followed a series of bangs and crashes.

Comment: "Do[es] there exist any other approaches?" As a BrE speaker, I think the numbers should to be consistent. "Does there exist any other approach?" or "Do there exist any other approaches?" But both of these sound rather old-fashioned compared with "Does any other approach exist?", "Do any other approaches exist?", or simply "Is there any other approach?", "Are there any other approaches?"

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing deep to understand really, this is basic question phrasing:

**Auxiliary + Subject + Verb (+ complement).**

In your first proposition, you completely forgot about the subject. Hence, the second proposition :

> Do **there exist** any other approaches?

Is the correct one.

To stick to yours a bit more, you could also use:

> Do **any other approaches** exist ?

Still following the "Auxiliary + Subject + Verb" syntax. To be frank, this second proposition sounds a lot better than the first one, to me.
**P.s:** If you're having any more trouble with question phrasing in English, keep in mind that figuring out the answer syntax is always the first, and may be most important, step of the process.

Comment: *Does there exist any other approach**es**?* is impossible: plural *approaches* requires *Do*.

Comment: You're right, I just figured that out minutes ago and edited barely before your comment, thanks for the reminder !