# "if there exists" or "if there exist"?

Tags: grammar

"Machine Learning: A Probabilistic Perspective by Kevin Patrick Murphy" in page 31 says

> iff there **exist** function g and h such that
>
> p(x, y|z) = g(x, z)h(y, z) ...

I guess **exist** here should be **exists**, is it?

Comment: The book actually says "iff there exist function**s** *g* and *h* such that…"

Answer (score 1):

Both forms are possible.

**If there exist.....** is the subjunctive form of the verb (about which you will find hundreds of illustrations on the net).

It's like saying:**If there be another challenger, let him come forward.** - a construction that has a somewhat poetic or theatrical ring.

There's also the question of whether you could interpret **function g and h** as a single function or a double function (although a single is indicated).

In practice, most people would probably use **exists**, as English speakers make ever less use of the subjunctive.

https://en.bab.la/conjugation/english/exist

Comment: Two problems: 1. "If there exist…" is indicative, agreeing with a plural subject in the conventional way; details [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/46968/6700). 2. "function _g_ and _h_" is a transcription error. That book has "functions _g_ and _h_".