# "That requires X be computed when accessed" versus "That requires X to be computed when it is accessed"

Tags: grammar

> That requires the Magnitude and Direction properties be computed when accessed.

Why is it not below?

> That requires the Magnitude and Direction properties **to be** computed when **they are** accessed.

What kind of grammar is applied in the original sentence (the first one above)?

Comment: Both are ambiguous, as to whether the properties are to be computed at the time of access, or required to be computed before any access is made. (Request access, compute, return; or compute, request access, return.) This is because *when* can mean "at/before the time that..." or "during the time that..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> That requires the Magnitude and Direction properties be computed when accessed.

There is a hidden declarative content clause.  I put back the omitted optional complementiser **that** for clarity:

> That requires [that] the Magnitude and Direction properties be computed when accessed.

Your 2nd version means the same as the original.

Edit to Incorporate the Subsequent Comments

In such a construction, with a that-clause, we use the subjunctive mood, and hence need the bare **be**, not **are**.

Comment: Can we replace `be`  with `are`?

Comment: In such a construction, with a that-clause, we use the subjunctive mood, and hence need the bare *be*, not *are*.

Comment: See [this too](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/46831/require-that-x-be-used-vs-require-x-to-be-used).

Answer (score 0):

1. "That **requires** the Magnitude and Direction properties **be computed**": "Requires" is followed by a subjunctive clause. It is an example of the [*mandative* use of the subjunctive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive#Triggering_contexts). As noted in the other answer, "that" can be inserted after "requires".
2. "**when accessed**": In an adverbial phrase, words like "when", "if", and "before" can introduce a reduced clause that begins with a participle. [This worksheet](https://www.mtsac.edu/writingcenter/dlas/reduced_adverb_clauses_dla_6-18-18.pdf) has some examples.