“Be represented” meaning
I encounter a sentence
“The district elections and the requirement that both renters and owners be represented will allow better representation of the diverse community”
where I don’t understand the meaning of the part “ owners be represented “
I expected the form of “to be” or “are represented” but not “be reresentred” alone. Does it have some special meaning?
When this form is used?
Thank you

Duplicate of this question https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/46831/require-that-x-be-used-vs-require-x-to-be-used

Certain verbs, and nouns formed from them, are complemented by clauses that use the bare form of the verb to mark  the clause as something other than a declaration of fact, such as a wish, a command, a requirement, a suggestion, a recommendation, and so on.

@TimR - the Mandative Subjunctive? After certain verbs (e.g. demand, insist, recommend, suggest) or adjectives (e.g. essential, important, vital).

@MichaelHarvey  Contemporary English grammar no longer uses that terminology. It's "old-school".  If I'm talking about a Robert Frost poem dating from around WWI, for example, I'll use it, because that's what Frost was taught. But it's not what kids in college are being taught nowadays.

"Both renters and owners be represented" is understood to say "both renters and owners be should represented."
